# Redirect Old domain to New domain with ssl nginx

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, nginx

I am trying to redirect old ssl domain to new ssl domain. But it is sending me redirection loop.

I have tried this configuration in nginx virtual host.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com old-domain.com; 
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    #SSL Configuration
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /home/username/example/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com old-domain.com;

    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

Please guide How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have a separate certificate file for the old domain?

Comment: certificate is same for both domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, the second `rewrite` statement is causing a redirection loop. The correct solution is to split the `server` block into two and redirect from one to the other, much the same way you redirect from `http` to `https`. You can use the first `server` block for this purpose.

The `server` block with `default_server` does not need a `server_name` directive, as it responds to all unmatched server names anyway. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details.

Assuming that these are the only `https` servers in this configuration, and that both `server` blocks share the same SSL configuration (as your comment suggests), the snippets files could be moved above to be *inherited* by both `server` blocks.

And finally, the `server_name` directive in the main `server` block only lists the server names that are **not** to be redirected.

For example:

```
include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got what I was doing wrong. This was really very helpful.